# Mongodb Query: Latest record by date for each item

Tags: mongodb, record

There are six devices in a collection, each has many records, some have records of new dates and some have week or/and month older. I need a query which returns latest last record of each device. In the case of .aggregate() I need that complete "data" filed.

Here is the sample json.

```
{
"date_time" : some-date
"device_id" : 27,
"gateway_id" : 1,
"data": [{"r" : 203,"v" : 3642},{"r" : 221,"v" : 3666}]
}
{
"date_time" : some-date
"device_id" : 28,
"gateway_id" : 1,
"data": [{"r" : 203,"v" : 3002},{"r" : 221,"v" : 3006}]
}
{
"date_time" : some-date
"device_id" : 29,
"gateway_id" : 1,
"data": [{"r" : 203,"v" : 3002}, {"r" : 221,"v" : 3006}]
}
```

I tried a lot of queries but no success.

Please not the following are not for this case.

```
db.col.find({"device_id": {"$in": devices}, "date_time": { "$gte": last_date}}) .sort({$natural: -1})

db.col.find({"device_id": {"$in": devices}, "date_time": { "$gte": last_date}}) .sort({$natural: -1}).limit(1)

db.col.find({"device_id": {"$in": devices}}) .sort({"date_time": -1}).limit(1)

db.col.find({"device_id": {"$in": devices}}) .sort({"_id": -1}).limit(1)
```

I am looking for the query which provides only latest record of every device in collection. Please note that in the case of .aggregate() I need  that complete "data" filed.

Comment: try with aggregate query. it will help to find same result you required

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with following snippet

```
db.collection.aggregate([
            {$group: {
                    "_id": "$device_id",
                    "gateway_id": {"$last":"$gateway_id"},
                     data: {$last: '$data'},
                     date: {$last: '$date_time'},
                }},
            {$project: {
                     "device_id": "$_id",
                      "gateway_id": "$gateway_id",
                      "data": "$data",
                      "date_time": "$date"
                  }},
            {$sort: {
                    'date': -1
                }}
        ])
```

In above query group by device id and date, data, and gateway_id will be latest in each row.

Output is-

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 29,
            "gateway_id" : 1,
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "r" : 203,
                    "v" : 3002
                }, 
                {
                    "r" : 221,
                    "v" : 3006
                }
            ],
            "device_id" : 29,
            "date_time" : "a"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 28,
            "gateway_id" : 1,
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "r" : 203,
                    "v" : 3002
                }, 
                {
                    "r" : 221,
                    "v" : 3006
                }
            ],
            "device_id" : 28,
            "date_time" : "b"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 27,
            "gateway_id" : 1,
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "r" : 203,
                    "v" : 3642
                }, 
                {
                    "r" : 221,
                    "v" : 3666
                }
            ],
            "device_id" : 27,
            "date_time" : "a"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to project all your required field through Accumulator Operator in  aggregation query. please have a look on this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/ link. i would like to see your output schema?

Comment: In query we have grouped rows by device_id, what you want in "data" field. Either last or first. i m not getting your original requirement

Comment: There are 3 devices, each device has a **data** array and record entry **date_time**, and each device has many records in same collection. Now I need that latest **data** array of all devices.

Comment: I have just updated my answer, you can view output of query which was seen at my console. please check and update me accordingly.

Comment: Dineshaws you are great, it works. With changes for my other requirements it is done, thanks a lot for the attention.

Comment: Welcome  Sajjad Ahmed, Glad to hear from you such words.

Comment: Hi [Dineshaws](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3441983/dineshaws) I need your attention for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672035/extract-two-sub-array-values-in-mongodb-by-elemmatch) regarding mongodb query.

Comment: @Dineshaws - Please explain the answer and the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use findOne instead of find Query
db.collection.findOne({})