# MongoDB - Query to get most recent price quote for each item

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to follow the example [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368141/mongodb-query-latest-record-by-date-for-each-item).

We have a database of millions of stock tickers and prices.  A common need is to get the last (most recent) row for each ticker symbol.  In the big database, we have compound indexes on ticker and the createdDateTime fields used below.

So there are two parts to the question:

1. What is best index to run efficiently to minimize IO and run time?
2. The aggregate query I'm doing below is returning 0 rows with the above test data.  It should return two rows, each with the latest time for a ticker.

```
import requests
import sys
import traceback
import pprint
import json
import bson
from datetime import datetime as datetime1
import datetime
from time import time
import time as time2
import configHandler
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as datetime1

startTime = time()
startDateNowFmt = datetime1.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
(config_dict, config_user_dict) = configHandler.getConfigVariables()

print("Start TestMongoDBQuerySpeedTuningAggregate, DateTime=" + str(startDateNowFmt))

cluster = MongoClient(config_dict['MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING'])
db = cluster[config_dict['MONGODB_CLUSTER']]
dbCollectionName = "TestQuotesAggregate"
dbCollection = db[dbCollectionName]

row1 = {'ticker': 'Test1',
        'timestampIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:31:15',
        'createdDateTimeYear': 2020,
        'createdDateTimeMonth': 9,
        'createdDateTimeDay': 29,
        'createdDateTimeHour': 15,
        'createdDateTimeMinute': 31,
        'todaysChangePerc': -11,
        'minuteClose': 100}

row2 = {'ticker': 'Test1',
        'timestampIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:32:15',
        'createdDateTimeYear': 2020,
        'createdDateTimeMonth': 9,
        'createdDateTimeDay': 29,
        'createdDateTimeHour': 15,
        'createdDateTimeMinute': 32,
        'todaysChangePerc': -11.1,
        'minuteClose': 99}

row3 = {'ticker': 'Test2',
        'timestampIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:31:15',
        'createdDateTimeYear': 2020,
        'createdDateTimeMonth': 9,
        'createdDateTimeDay': 29,
        'createdDateTimeHour': 15,
        'createdDateTimeMinute': 31,
        'todaysChangePerc': -12,
        'minuteClose': 200}

row4 = {'ticker': 'Test2',
        'timestampIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:32:15',
        'createdDateTimeYear': 2020,
        'createdDateTimeMonth': 9,
        'createdDateTimeDay': 29,
        'createdDateTimeHour': 15,
        'createdDateTimeMinute': 32,
        'todaysChangePerc': -12.1,
        'minuteClose': 195}

doInsert = False   # only need to do this first time

if doInsert:
    insert_rows = [row1, row2, row3, row4]
    dbCollection.insert_many(insert_rows)



print("Before aggregation - show the data we have to work with")
docs1 = dbCollection.find({})
for doc in docs1:
    print(doc['ticker'], doc['minuteClose'], doc['todaysChangePerc'])

# {"todaysChangePerc": {'$lt': -10}},
docs = dbCollection.aggregate([
            {'$match': {
                      '$and': [
                               {'todaysChangePerc': {'$lt': -10}},
                               {'createdDateTimeYear': 2020},
                               {'createdDateTimeMonth': 9},
                               {'createdDateTimeDay': 29},
                               {'createdDateTimeHour': 15},
                               {'createdDateTimeMinute': {"$gt": 49}}
                      ]
            }},
            {'$group': {
                    '_id': '$ticker',
                    'temp_data': {'$last': '$createdDateTimeIsoDateTime'},
                                  'minuteClose': {'$last': '$minuteClose'},
                                  'todaysChangePerc': {'$last': '$todaysChangePerc'}
            }},
            {'$project': {
                     'ticker_id': '$_id',
                     'minuteClose': '$minuteClose',
                     'todaysChangePerc': '$todaysChangePerc'
            }},
            {'$sort': {
                    'timestampIsoDateTime': -1
            }}
        ])


# pprint.pprint(docs.explain())

# pprint.pprint(docs)
countDocs = 0
print("After aggregation - show the data we have to work with")
for doc in docs:
    print(doc['ticker'], doc['minuteClose'], doc['todaysChangePerc'])
    countDocs += 1


endTime = time()
# print("StartTime=" + str(startTime) + " EndTime=" + str(endTime))
elapsedTime = endTime - startTime
endDateNowFmt = datetime1.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print("\n")
print("Count Docs:", countDocs)
print("Server Start DateTime=" + str(startDateNowFmt))
print("Server End   DateTime=" + str(endDateNowFmt))
print("ElapsedTime=" + str(elapsedTime) + " seconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my rush to create a reproducible sample, I had a couple of errors:

1. I added createdDateTimeIsoDateTime to each of my four test rows
2. In the final print, I had to user ticker_id instead of ticker.  Was getting a key error.

Here is the corrected code, I'm stilling doing some testing and quality assurance to determine that it is correct:

```
import requests
import sys
import traceback
import pprint
import json
import bson
from datetime import datetime as datetime1
import datetime
from time import time
import time as time2
import configHandler
#import boto3
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as datetime1

##########################################################################################
startTime = time()
startDateNowFmt = datetime1.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
(config_dict, config_user_dict) = configHandler.getConfigVariables()


print("Start TestMongoDBQuerySpeedTuningAggregate, DateTime=" + str(startDateNowFmt))

# print ("ConnectionString:"  + config_dict['MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING'])
cluster = MongoClient(config_dict['MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING'])
db = cluster[config_dict['MONGODB_CLUSTER']]
dbCollectionName = "TestQuotesAggregate"
# dbCollectionName = "ProdPolygonIOQuotes"
dbCollection = db[dbCollectionName]

doInsert = True    # only need to do this first time

if doInsert:

    row1 = {'ticker': 'Test1',
            'timestampIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:31:15',
            'createdDateTimeIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:31:15',
            'createdDateTimeYear': 2020,
            'createdDateTimeMonth': 9,
            'createdDateTimeDay': 29,
            'createdDateTimeHour': 15,
            'createdDateTimeMinute': 31,
            'todaysChangePerc': -11,
            'minuteClose': 100}

    row2 = {'ticker': 'Test1',
            'timestampIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:32:15',
            'createdDateTimeIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:32:15',
            'createdDateTimeYear': 2020,
            'createdDateTimeMonth': 9,
            'createdDateTimeDay': 29,
            'createdDateTimeHour': 15,
            'createdDateTimeMinute': 32,
            'todaysChangePerc': -11.1,
            'minuteClose': 99}

    row3 = {'ticker': 'Test2',
            'timestampIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:31:15',
            'createdDateTimeIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:31:15',
            'createdDateTimeYear': 2020,
            'createdDateTimeMonth': 9,
            'createdDateTimeDay': 29,
            'createdDateTimeHour': 15,
            'createdDateTimeMinute': 31,
            'todaysChangePerc': -12,
            'minuteClose': 200}

    row4 = {'ticker': 'Test2',
            'timestampIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:32:15',
            'createdDateTimeIsoDateTime': '2020-09-29T15:31:15',
            'createdDateTimeYear': 2020,
            'createdDateTimeMonth': 9,
            'createdDateTimeDay': 29,
            'createdDateTimeHour': 15,
            'createdDateTimeMinute': 32,
            'todaysChangePerc': -12.1,
            'minuteClose': 195}

    insert_rows = [row1, row2, row3, row4]
    dbCollection.insert_many(insert_rows)



print("Before aggregation - show the data we have to work with")
docs1 = dbCollection.find({})
for doc in docs1:
    print(doc['ticker'], doc['createdDateTimeIsoDateTime'], doc['minuteClose'], doc['todaysChangePerc'])

docs = dbCollection.aggregate([
            {'$match': {
                      '$and': [
                               {'todaysChangePerc': {'$lt': -10}},
                               {'createdDateTimeYear': 2020},
                               {'createdDateTimeMonth': 9},
                               {'createdDateTimeDay': 29},
                               {'createdDateTimeHour': 15},
                               {'createdDateTimeMinute': {"$gt": 1}}
                      ]
            }},
            {'$group': {
                    '_id': '$ticker',
                    'temp_data': {'$last': '$createdDateTimeIsoDateTime'},
                                  'minuteClose': {'$last': '$minuteClose'},
                                  'todaysChangePerc': {'$last': '$todaysChangePerc'}
            }},
            {'$project': {
                     'ticker_id': '$_id',
                     'minuteClose': '$minuteClose',
                     'todaysChangePerc': '$todaysChangePerc'
            }},
            {'$sort': {
                    'timestampIsoDateTime': -1
            }}
        ])


#pprint.pprint(docs.explain())

# pprint.pprint(docs)
countDocs = 0
print("After aggregation - show the data we have to work with")
for doc in docs:
    print(doc['ticker_id'], doc['minuteClose'], doc['todaysChangePerc'])
    countDocs += 1


endTime = time()
# print("StartTime=" + str(startTime) + " EndTime=" + str(endTime))
elapsedTime = endTime - startTime
endDateNowFmt = datetime1.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print("\n")
print("Count Docs:", countDocs)
print("Server Start DateTime=" + str(startDateNowFmt))
print("Server End   DateTime=" + str(endDateNowFmt))
print("ElapsedTime=" + str(elapsedTime) + " seconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

A second improvement, if any one can verify that my new sort between the $match and the $group is correct?

In order for $last to work, the rows needed to be sorted before the $last statement is used.  Then at the end, I can sort by ticker symbol for the final data listing.

```
docs = dbCollection.aggregate([
            {'$match': {
                      '$and': [
                               {'todaysChangePerc': {'$lt': -10}},
                               {'createdDateTimeYear': 2020},
                               {'createdDateTimeMonth': 9},
                               {'createdDateTimeDay': 29},
                               {'createdDateTimeHour': 15},
                               {'createdDateTimeMinute': {"$gt": 1}}
                      ]
            }},
            {'$sort': {
                    'ticker': 1,
                    'timestampIsoDateTime': 1
            }},
            {'$group': {
                    '_id': '$ticker',
                    'temp_data': {'$last': '$createdDateTimeIsoDateTime'},
                                  'minuteClose': {'$last': '$minuteClose'},
                                  'todaysChangePerc': {'$last': '$todaysChangePerc'},
                                  'timestampIsoDateTime': {'$last': '$timestampIsoDateTime'}
            }},
            {'$project': {
                     'ticker': '$_id',
                     'minuteClose': '$minuteClose',
                     'todaysChangePerc': '$todaysChangePerc',
                     'timestampIsoDateTime': '$timestampIsoDateTime'
            }},
            {'$sort': {
                    'ticker': 1
            }}
        ])
```